# Iterating through excel column (remember last Row, then resume iteration after some time)

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I am trying to create a script that retrieves values from an excel column. New values are constantly entered into the column. I want the script to run every day eg at 6am calculating the 'new' average. I want it to remember the last row cell that it used the previous day then calculate an average based on the newly entered values this past new day.

```py
import openpyxl


# Calculate Average CF
def ave(lst):
    return round(sum(lst) / len(lst), 2)


# Save today's Ave. CF and last row used for calculation
def save_ave(average, last_cell):
    with open('Prac.txt', 'a') as fw:
        summary = f'Average is: {average}, and last calculated cell={last_cell}\n'
        fw.write(summary)


# Open excel file
cm_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Process Dashboard - Copy.xlsx',read_only=True, data_only=True)
# Retrieve names of all sheets in opened excel file
cm_sheets = cm_wb.sheetnames
# Specify sheet to work with (eg last sheet)
cm2_sheet = cm_wb[cm_sheets[len(cm_sheets) - 1]]
# Declare empty list to store values which we'l use to calculate Ave.
t = []

# Open text file in which our average values are stored and corresponding last row used
with open('Prac.txt', 'r') as fr:
    file_lines = [line.strip() for line in fr.readlines()]
    if not file_lines:
        # If file is initially empty, we'll start iterating from Row 1
        first_row = 1
    else:
        # After 1st time run, retrieve the stored last row value
        cell = file_lines[-1].split('=')
        # We'll start iterating from last used row + 1
        first_row = int(cell[-1]) + 1

# Iterations to be made to last entry in column
last_row = cm2_sheet.max_row

# Iterate column E
for row in cm2_sheet.iter_rows(min_row=first_row, max_row=last_row, max_col=5, min_col=5):
    # Each value into list t
    for i in row:
        t.append(i.value)

# Calculate the average, and store last used row in file
save_ave(ave(t), last_row)

# Close the file to allow other programs to use
cm_wb.close()
```

Comment: It looks like you have an implementation to get the average, store it, and retrieve it from file. What exactly is the question? Is it erring out with a stack trace? Or are you trying to figure out how to schedule it as a background task with the OS?

Comment: Is there no efficient and more 'compact' way of doing this ? Instead of writing to a file ? I'm a beginer and i was thinking there is a better way of doing it than what i have suggested.

Comment: It's really not much of a target for optimization in my view. It's just a quick task that's done once every not so often. The thing that I'd be thinking about is the reliability of the solution. Is it going to work for all your users. If it's an application that runs on people's individual systems which may not all be the same OS, then the `appdirs` module would be a good tool to use to make sure your config data or application state is stored in the right folder. But that really depends on the application - if it makes sense to have such a solution.

Comment: I will certainly look into use of appdirs. The idea is to have the application run daily at 6am, on different PCs on a network with same windows OS. The average was just an example calculation to find an efficient way of iterating through rows and remember where it last stopped.